# React Native BUILD SUCCEED, but "No devices are booted."

Tags: react-native

Here's my environment:

```
➜  AwesomeProject node --version
v6.3.0
➜  AwesomeProject npm --version
3.10.3
➜  AwesomeProject react-native --version
react-native-cli: 1.0.0
react-native: 0.29.0
➜  AwesomeProject watchman --version
3.0.0
```

`Xcode version 7.3.1`

I created the `AwesomeProject` described on: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html#content

Then execute: `sudo react-native run-ios`

Here's what I'm getting:

```
...
    export SYSTEM_DEVELOPER_USR_DIR=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr
    export SYSTEM_DEVELOPER_UTILITIES_DIR=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Applications/Utilities
    export SYSTEM_DOCUMENTATION_DIR=/Library/Documentation
    export SYSTEM_KEXT_INSTALL_PATH=/System/Library/Extensions
    export SYSTEM_LIBRARY_DIR=/System/Library
    export TAPI_VERIFY_MODE=ErrorsOnly
    export TARGETED_DEVICE_FAMILY=1
    export TARGETNAME=AwesomeProject
    export TARGET_BUILD_DIR=/Users/glaksmono/Documents/React/AwesomeProject/ios/build/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator
    export TARGET_DEVICE_MODEL=iPhone7,2
    export TARGET_DEVICE_OS_VERSION=9.3
    export TARGET_NAME=AwesomeProject
    export TARGET_TEMP_DIR=/Users/glaksmono/Documents/React/AwesomeProject/ios/build/Build/Intermediates/AwesomeProject.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/AwesomeProject.build
    export TEMP_DIR=/Users/glaksmono/Documents/React/AwesomeProject/ios/build/Build/Intermediates/AwesomeProject.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/AwesomeProject.build
    export TEMP_FILES_DIR=/Users/glaksmono/Documents/React/AwesomeProject/ios/build/Build/Intermediates/AwesomeProject.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/AwesomeProject.build
    export TEMP_FILE_DIR=/Users/glaksmono/Documents/React/AwesomeProject/ios/build/Build/Intermediates/AwesomeProject.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/AwesomeProject.build
    export TEMP_ROOT=/Users/glaksmono/Documents/React/AwesomeProject/ios/build/Build/Intermediates
    export TOOLCHAINS=com.apple.dt.toolchain.XcodeDefault
    export TOOLCHAIN_DIR=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain
    export TREAT_MISSING_BASELINES_AS_TEST_FAILURES=NO
    export UID=0
    export UNLOCALIZED_RESOURCES_FOLDER_PATH=AwesomeProject.app
    export UNSTRIPPED_PRODUCT=NO
    export USER=root
    export USER_APPS_DIR=/var/root/Applications
    export USER_LIBRARY_DIR=/var/root/Library
    export USE_DYNAMIC_NO_PIC=YES
    export USE_HEADERMAP=YES
    export USE_HEADER_SYMLINKS=NO
    export VALIDATE_PRODUCT=NO
    export VALID_ARCHS="i386 x86_64"
    export VERBOSE_PBXCP=NO
    export VERSIONPLIST_PATH=AwesomeProject.app/version.plist
    export VERSION_INFO_BUILDER=root
    export VERSION_INFO_FILE=AwesomeProject_vers.c
    export VERSION_INFO_STRING="\"@(#)PROGRAM:AwesomeProject  PROJECT:AwesomeProject-\""
    export WRAPPER_EXTENSION=app
    export WRAPPER_NAME=AwesomeProject.app
    export WRAPPER_SUFFIX=.app
    export WRAP_ASSET_PACKS_IN_SEPARATE_DIRECTORIES=NO
    export XCODE_APP_SUPPORT_DIR=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Xcode
    export XCODE_PRODUCT_BUILD_VERSION=7D1014
    export XCODE_VERSION_ACTUAL=0731
    export XCODE_VERSION_MAJOR=0700
    export XCODE_VERSION_MINOR=0730
    export XPCSERVICES_FOLDER_PATH=AwesomeProject.app/XPCServices
    export YACC=yacc
    export arch=x86_64
    export diagnostic_message_length=124
    export variant=normal
    /bin/sh -c /Users/glaksmono/Documents/React/AwesomeProject/ios/build/Build/Intermediates/AwesomeProject.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/AwesomeProject.build/Script-00DD1BFF1BD5951E006B06BC.sh
Skipping bundling for Simulator platform

=== BUILD TARGET AwesomeProjectTests OF PROJECT AwesomeProject WITH CONFIGURATION Debug ===

Check dependencies

** BUILD SUCCEEDED **

Installing build/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/AwesomeProject.app
No devices are booted.
Launching org.reactjs.native.example.AwesomeProject
No devices are booted.
```

And the iOS iPhone 6 simulator is just showing a black screen.

Ideas?

Comment: Try to reset your simulator and try to run.

Comment: @Tirth , I tried that by `Command + Q`, then re-run, still the same :(

Comment: Command+Q will nothing happens.. you just quit simulator and reset it. If you want reset it then Simulator tab bar select Reset Simulator and settings options.

Comment: @Tirth doesn't seem to work for me. It just reset the device, but when I run it again, it just stays..

Comment: Tryed all the comments, nothing helped.

Answer (score 28):

When hitting `react-native run-ios`, one of the first lines printed to console, would be something like this (or similar)

```
Launching iPhone 6 (10.0)...
```

1. Boot the respective simulator manually

   - Go to [spotlight search](https://support.apple.com/en-bh/HT204014) and start to type *simulator*
   - When spotlight presents the search result, choose the simulator app and hit Enter
   - Go to simulator app's menu: Hardwire -> Device -> iOS 10.0 -> iPhone 6 and select it
2. Reset

   - Go to simulator app's menu: Simulator -> Reset Content and Settings...
3. Retry

   - Command `react-native run-ios` again

Answer (score 7):

I have just solved the same question.

First try using `react-native run-ios` instead of the `sudo react-native run-ios`.

Next try the following:

In file `AppDelegate.m`, change

```
jsCodeLocation = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://localhost:8081/index.ios.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true"];
```

To:

```
jsCodeLocation = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://127.0.0.1:8081/index.ios.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true"];
```

(This may be a security issue with iOS 9);

Next try to reset your env.

Comment: This works, though there are warnings about permission denied when not run with sudo, hope they won't come to bite me later?
Do you have any idea why it works without sudo but not with?

Comment: Cant run without sudo ;// mac os sierra here. Device still not found.

Comment: Also same for me.

Answer (score 5):

I have the same problem when first time to run `react-native run-ios`
Try Hardware -> Reboot the simulator, and run it again.

Answer (score 5):

I ran into this problem when I ran `react-native run-ios` within the terminal multiplexer `tmux`. I fixed it by running `react-native run-ios` in a normal terminal tab without `tmux` running.

Comment: you just saved me hours!

Answer (score 5):

Try **NOT** running the command `react-native run-ios` as `root`

Answer (score 2):

I rebooted the simulator as suggested above tried config reset but no luck.

However while the simulator is open, I went to `/Users/username/projectdirectorry/AwesomeProject/ios/build`

**dragged** the AwesomeProject.app on the simulator and it is worked.

Comment: Wow, it worked for me, go to path Your-Project-Directory/ios/build/Your-Project-Name/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Your-Project-Name. Drag Your-Project-Name(Probably on top) into simulator

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar problem so I opened it up in Xcode and built the project from there. The issue was that no device was selected. Xcode will tell you that when you try to build.

Answer (score 0):

Ran into the same problem. `Hardware` > `Restart` fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

This is old question but I understand people run into this even today. Posting what I saw as a solution for me.

#### Try opening simulator on your Mac as-is without react-native. If you are able to open simulator via Xcode, you will be able to open it via react-native command.

I noticed I needed to free-up system resources to be able to open any new simulator instances. I killed few processes, was able to open simulator via Xcode and then via react-native too.

Good luck!