# React Native: Successfully boots simulator, but application does not completely open, index.ios.js build

Tags: reactjs, react-native, ios-simulator, xcode10

I have Xcode 10.1 on my machine.

Yesterday I cloned a React Native project and did an `npm install` as well as `npm install --save react-native-cli` so I could use the Simulator as this project seems to be created to go straight to build and be somehow debugged from an ipa/ipk build, not sure how that works, but I am used to debugging from Simulator.

Today, I attempted to boot up simulator, initially it booted up to the point where I could see the app logo and that's as far as it went. I closed it down and attempted to reboot it and it goes through this:

```
** BUILD SUCCEEDED **


Installing build/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/AppName.app
Launching com.nist.appname
```

but the Simulator does not boot up. The following OP helped resolving the Simulator from not booting up again:

[React Native BUILD SUCCEED, but "No devices are booted."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38293243/react-native-build-succeed-but-no-devices-are-booted)

However, now the simulator boots up, but the application does not completely boot up, it stops at the display of the application logo.

Today I learned that it was indeed built with `react-native-cli` to run `react-native run-ios`, but I guess I initially was expecting to see it in the `package.json` file, so I don't know if installing it twice caused an issue, but I don't think so, since it did not give me a problem yesterday when I did it.

I believe the problem is `index.ios.js` build fails. Not sure how to debug that. This is the `index.io.js` file:

```
import {AppRegistry} from 'react-native';
import KeyboardManager from 'react-native-keyboard-manager';
import AppName from './App';

KeyboardManager.setToolbarPreviousNextButtonEnable(true);

AppRegistry.registerComponent('AppName', () => AppName);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was with an import statement in one of the `action.js` files.

Instead of `import types from './constants';` like the rest of the types files or constant files, it had `import types from './types';`

After I corrected that, the `index.ios.js` build was succeeding again.